# Font Awesome Icons won't show?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I did the exact required steps in the website and still it doesn't work..

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3e91539bf3.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>About Me</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-person-booth"></i>My Builds</a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clock"></i>Get in-touch</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try it should work .

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can say that's because of the version mismatch, you can try font awesome 4.7 as it is included in bootstrap cdn.

**Copy to the head of html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <i class="fa fa-5x fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-5x"></i>
</body>
</html>
```